# Preparing for Hyperforce Migration

Tags: api, mobile, hyperforce

My Salesforce org will be migrating to hyperforce. In order to do that there are a few things Saleforce wants us to do. I am not at all familiar with the following:

[image]
[image]

Look for reference here : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392992&type=1

Now, my question has two parts:

1. If there are any mobile applications pinned to entity certificate:
   How to know how many mobile apps are there and whether they are pinned or not?
2. If there are any API pinned to entity certificate: How to know how many APIs are there and whether they are pinned or not?